# issue with FILE

Tags: c, file, stdout, stdio

I'm getting the folowing error for below code,
"1506-221 (S) Initializer must be a valid constant expression"

```
FILE          *fp[] = {stdout, dump_f};
```

is this acceptable? what is the proper way to achive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error suggests that on your system the `stdout` variable is in fact a `#defined` macro which expands to a function call.

Actually, as others have suggested, it's probably just that `stdout` is an extern declared variable whose value is not known at compile time and therefore can't be supplied in a static initializer.

Regardless of which, the solution should be the same - I'd try something like:

```
FILE *fp[2];

void init_fp()
{
    fp[0] = stdout;
    fp[1] = dump_f;
}
```

Comment: How would a macro affect the result?

Answer (score 2):

If that is a global, then C does not support initializing it with a function call. If `stdout` is a macro (as suggested initially) for a function call, then you won't be able to use it to initialize a global.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely, `stdout` and/or `dump_f` are macros or (more likely the problem) external globals.

If I have this code:

```
// external.c
int hello = 1234;

// external.h
extern int hello;

// main.c
#include "external.h"

int world = hello; // error!
```

You would receive an error at the indicated line because the value of `hello` is not known.

`stdout` and `dump_f` are most likely declared as `extern` globals, like so:

```
extern FILE *stdout, *stdin, *stderr, *dump_f;
```

Answer (score 2):

Classically, most Unix systems used to define `stdout` as something like `(&_iob[1])`, which reduced to a valid constant expression; Solaris, for instance, still does.

A few years ago, now, the GNU C Library changed its definition of `stdout` to something that was not a constant, so old code which used to initialize `FILE *` variables to any of the standard file pointers ceased to compile.  This is sanctioned by the C standard, so there is no virtue in complaining.  You simply have to accept that you cannot initialize static file pointers to one of the standard I/O channels and recode to get around the problem.  (But it *is* still a nuisance.)

Comment: Yet another reason to hate the FSF.